# Incorporating a second total count query for conditional loops in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP page with script that displays rows based off of the "year" that is selected. This is executed by the $_GET from URL string and then a variable is used inside my MySQL query.

`$jID = (int)$_GET['id'];`

```
SELECT lh.*, c.country AS c, c.flag, MAX(countv) countv, MAX(counta) counta
FROM (
      SELECT vg.vertrekluchthaven AS code, count(*) as countv, 0 as counta
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
      WHERE year(vg.vertrekdatum2) = '$jID'
      GROUP BY vg.vertrekluchthaven

    UNION  

      SELECT vg.aankomstluchthaven AS code, 0 as countv, count(*) as counta
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
      WHERE year(vg.vertrekdatum2) = '$jID'
      GROUP BY vg.aankomstluchthaven
   ) vg

LEFT JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
ON  lh.luchthavenID = vg.code

LEFT JOIN tbl_countries c
ON lh.countryID = c.countryID 

GROUP BY vg.code
ORDER BY lh.luchthavencode;
```

`?id=2018` might produce

```
| Code | Name                       | # Arrival | # Depart |
| AMS  | Amsterdam                  | 3         | 2        |
| MSP  | Minneapolis                | 5         | 5        |
| TLL  | Tallinn                    | 1         | 1        |
```

I'd like to also count ALL rows and then use conditions in the loop that would bold & red (or some other format) if the count is <= 0 for the entire table that is now <= the `$_GET` value.

Would there be a way to add a subquery within that gives me the total count of the UNION query as a column, such as:

```
| Code | Name                       | # Arrival | # Depart | # Total |
| AMS  | Amsterdam                  | 3         | 2        | 64      |
| MSP  | Minneapolis                | 5         | 5        | 122     |
| TLL  | Tallinn                    | 1         | 1        | 1       |


FROM (
          SELECT vg.vertrekluchthaven AS code, count(*) as countv, 0 as counta
          FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
          WHERE year(vg.vertrekdatum2) <= '$jID'
          GROUP BY vg.vertrekluchthaven

        UNION  

          SELECT vg.aankomstluchthaven AS code, 0 as countv, count(*) as counta
          FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
          WHERE year(vg.vertrekdatum2) <= '$jID'
          GROUP BY vg.aankomstluchthaven
       ) vg
```

Then I can just use the `if ($row['totalcount'] >0)` / else clause for conditional formatting within PHP.

Comment: How is the total count related to arrival and depart?

Comment: they are not directly related. In the query present, I have via a UNION determined the countv (depart) and counta (arrival). I suspect that another UNION would be needed somehow, only instead of using the counta and countv counts, i would just do a count in the SELECT and group by the code, though I've not ever done anything like this before.

Comment: So what is `total` counting?

Comment: it would basically be doing the same UNION query results that are being obtained only instead of being an = '$jID' it would be doing a <= '$jID'  This would be in addition to the = results, which are providing me with the counta and the countv.. All still being grouped by vg.code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's hard to be certain without sample data, based on your comments I think you can achieve what you want by running your subquery on all dates `<= $jID` and then using conditional aggregation to get the values for the specific year you are interested in:

```
SELECT lh.*, c.country AS c, c.flag, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN vg.year = '$jID' THEN countv END) AS countv, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN vg.year = '$jID' THEN counta END) AS counta,
       SUM(counta)+SUM(countv) AS total
FROM (
      SELECT vg.vertrekluchthaven AS code, year(vg.vertrekdatum2) AS year, count(*) as countv, 0 as counta
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
      WHERE year(vg.vertrekdatum2) <= '$jID'
      GROUP BY code, year

    UNION  

      SELECT vg.aankomstluchthaven AS code, year(vg.vertrekdatum2) AS year, 0 as countv, count(*) as counta
      FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
      WHERE year(vg.vertrekdatum2) <= '$jID'
      GROUP BY code, year
   ) vg

LEFT JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
ON  lh.luchthavenID = vg.code

LEFT JOIN tbl_countries c
ON lh.countryID = c.countryID 

GROUP BY vg.code
ORDER BY lh.luchthavencode;
```

Comment: thanks for that, Nick. I think it will work. I'll need to add a WHERE statement in my statement (outside of the UNION) but that's easy enough. Thanks so much for your help. It's much appreciated!

Comment: @DaniëlCronk why do you need a `WHERE` statement?

Comment: thanks & sorry. I am currently traveling and so my online time is limited. yes, ultimately your response did what I mostly needed. The only thing I was trying to figure out how to handle was that it brought back all records from the database when I really only wanted to see the current year ($jID).

Comment: Ultimately, I added a column using (SUM(counta)+SUM(countv)-(SUM(CASE WHEN vg.year = '$jID' THEN countv END) + SUM(CASE WHEN vg.year = '$jID' THEN counta END)) AS PreYear) to give me the number of visits prior to the current year and then using if/else statement logic, was able to do conditional formatting the way I was hoping. Thanks again for your help. I've not used the CASE in a SQL statement before so this was interesting.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk no worries - the easiest way to exclude prior years is to add a `HAVING countv > 0 OR counta > 0` clause after the `GROUP BY` as those values will only be non-zero for the current year.

Comment: oh. that worked perfect! I think you've been a great help and I've learned something new... Thanks for your help. greatly appreciated!